# Authorized REST API calls using apps script.

Tags: google-apps-script

I am building an application that consists of two strongly separated parts:

Backend server is running on AppEngine that access gsuite domain data using Google service account.

Spreadsheet plugin written with Apps Script, that is directly installed by the users.

Spreadsheet plugin should access backend server REST endpoint.

I want to implement authorization for the "Apps Script" -> "Backend Server" connection. The only information I found on this [Make requests to services with OAuth](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/external)

I don't want to implement my own user management and want to use the Google Accounts for authorization. As far as I understand the single way to do this is implement OAuth on the server side and then follow o.

I wonder if there a better approach or best practices to implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there isn't another mode of "authorisation" besides the one you've already mentioned/explored i.e OAuth.

What I would recommend as an alternate is to use JSON Web Tokens (JWTs).

Twilio's Authy uses it to [create user registrations without any PIIs](https://www.twilio.com/docs/authy/api/users?code-sample=code-no-pii-user-registration-jwt-5&code-language=JSON&code-sdk-version=default#create-a-jwt) and [JWTs in Google Apps Script](https://wtfruby.com/gas/2018/11/21/jwt-app-scripts.html) should help you with that.

Hope this helps.